# how to get final categories which has no childs in mysql?

Tags: mysql

how to get final categories which has no childs in mysql?
the result I want to get from the table below is 
3,5,6 .
they has no child categories.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for `cat`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cat`;
CREATE TABLE `cat` (
  `categories_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `parent_id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`categories_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of cat
-- ----------------------------
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('1', '0');
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('2', '1');
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('3', '1');
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('4', '2');
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('5', '0');
INSERT INTO `cat` VALUES ('6', '4');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from cat where categories_id not in (select parent_id from cat)
```

Is it what you asking for?

Same can be acheived through

```
select * from cat child 
left join cat parent on child.categories_id = parent.parent_id
where parent.parent_id is null
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9e75c/3)

Answer (score 1):

Use a left self-join:

```
select c1.categories_id
from cat c1
left join cat c2
on c2.parent_id = c1.categories_id
where c2.categories_id IS NULL
```

Comment: on c2.parent_id = c1.categories_id :) syntax

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from cat where categories_id = "0";
```

Or you can do Akhil's query. If this is what you have been asking